# Javascript eval fails on complicated json array

Tags: javascript, json, eval

I want to convert a json string to object by eval, but it fails with error like:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier   VM250:1

below is my string:
'[{"quiz_id":"3","_id":"1",**"option_in_json":"[{\"option\":\"1\",\"is_answer\":false},{\"option\":\"2\",\"is_answer\":true}]"**,"question":"1+1"}]';

Seems there is something wrong in the bold part, but i don't know how to fix it
The code below is not working

```js
var m='[{"quiz_id":"3","_id":"1","option_in_json":"[{\"option\":\"1\",\"is_answer\":false},{\"option\":\"2\",\"is_answer\":true}]","question":"1+1"}]';
eval(m);
```

The code below is working so i think the data structure of this json string is ok

```
var m=[{"quiz_id":"3","_id":"1","option_in_json":"[{\"option\":\"1\",\"is_answer\":false},{\"option\":\"2\",\"is_answer\":true}]","question":"1+1"}];
alert(m[0].option_in_json);
```

Also tried with $.parseJSON with no luck

Answer (score 4):

It does not work because you are not escaping the data inside the string literal correctly. Look at the value of `m` in the first case, especially the quotation marks:

```
[{"option_in_json":"[{"option":"1","is_answer":false}]","question":"1+1"}]
//                 ^  ^
```

I removed some irrelevant data. You should be able to see that this cannot be valid JavaScript (or JSON), because the quotation mark before `option` terminates the string.

In order to put the data inside a string literal, you should either fix the data so that it doesn't contain nested JSON, or escape `\`:

```
'[{"option_in_json":"[{\\"option\\": ... }]"}]'
```

Better of course if you are not putting it in a string literal in the first place.

```
var m='[{"quiz_id":"3","_id":"1","option_in_json": [{"option":"1","is_answer":false},{"option":"2","is_answer":true}],"question":"1+1"}]';
//                                                ^-- don't wrap in "" so no need to escape inner double quotes.

console.dir(JSON.parse(m));
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Felix, thanks very much for the quick answer and link,it solved my problem